# Sending less parameters in HTTP POST request than required

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I want to alter values on a back end e-commerce platform via HTTP POST requests(The platform has no public facing API). This is working great when I send the full request to the correct url.

```
payload ={
     'CourseName': 'Example ',
     'CourseID': '34 ',
     'mode': 'add ',
     'TableCode': '20',
     'Variations':' ',
     'ValueToUpdate':' ',
}
```

Except my payload has significantly more parameters than this. Every time I update a product I don't want to be filling the payload with the current data on the system for that particular product then making my changes.

Is it possible to just pass the parameters you want to change?

```
payload = {

    'CourseID':'34'
    'mode':'update',
    'ValueToUpdate':'info'

}
```

My attempts have resulted in 500 Internal server errors. Below are the request headers.

```
 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 861
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: What is the 500 error message when you send less parameters? It is possible to send less parameters for sure, but it depends on the endpoint to accept the request or not

Comment: @LucasWieloch Isn't that information only available server side? Code I use to get response: `print(item_posted.status_code, item_posted.reason)`. I haven't found another func in the requests docs to see what error the server is showing.

Comment: Yes ofc, my mistake. Still, if you remove a feel parameters from the payload and get a 500, the problem of sending less parameters should be solved server side (since it is crashing when you do it). There isn't anything wrong in your side

Comment: @LucasWieloch Interesting. So does that also mean a payload can be sent in any order? So {CourseName:'val','mode':'val'} == {'mode':'val',CourseName:'val'}

Comment: That's really upsetting if it is just the server. Because I have no access to it. It is good to know that if the backend code is configured correctly that shortened requests work. I read in another Stack post that a HTTP POST request essentially sends a new document over every time, which made me think that the headers had to align or something

Comment: The web itself is stateless. Each request must be complete in it's scope. If you're updating something with a POST request, the server already have all the data stored somewhere, except the things you're updating.